# Intercept calls to controllers

Tags: angularjs

Can I intercept the calls to my controllers methods?
I searching for something like Castle Windsor Proxy objects interceptos, for implementing something like AOP.

For example:

```
<button ng-click="buttonClick()"/>
<button ng-click="i = i + 1"/>
```

I want to find how to ejecute some code before and after ng-click perform.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a directive to intercept the click event for any element.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="buttonClick()" intercept-click />
```

JavaScript:

```
app.directive('interceptClick', function() {
  return {
    priority: 1,
    terminal: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      var clickAction = attr.ngClick;
      element.bind('click',function () {
        // Do something before executing the click action
        scope.$eval(clickAction);
        // Do something after executing the click action
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I would like something more general but by the moment I'm going to use it. Thanks, if you notice something more about it let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

[I am not sure if a general approach can be achieved] 
Here is a jsfiddle that combines Dennis's method
where you simply reuse existing ngclick directive.

```
myApp.directive('ngClick', function() { 
  return {  
      restrict:'A',

      link: {
           pre: function(scope,element){
              element.bind('click',function () {        
                console.log('interceptor');                    
                 // scope.$eval(clickAction);
                // Do something after executing the click action
              });
          }
      }
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6191/

Comment: As I have say ng-click is only an example ... this isn't I am searchig. Thank.